# When did books first become affordable to the general population?

Tags: economy, book

Gutenberg certainly had a great impact on the availability of books, but his printing press didn't help bring books into the hands of the poor. The price of books dropped from thousands of days worth of wages to hundreds, but this was  still far too expensive for commoners.

By the 17th century many commoners in Europe could read, but they probably had nothing more to read than the Bible which I would guess was sponsored or at least heavily subsidized to make it affordable. The poor still couldn't afford to just go to a bookstore and buy any book they fancied.

Compare it with the 20th century and onward, when books can be bought with pocket change.

When did books first become affordable to the poor? This means that even low income families could afford, if they wanted, to own several books without significant financial sacrifices. In the early to mid 19th century there were already popular authors in Europe who wrote for the tastes of the poorer classes, so I would guess it was around that time, but can this guess be improved upon?

Comment: For a person living hand-to-mouth, anything more than free isn't going to be "affordable".

Comment: Public libraries can be see as "free" in this context I think.

Comment: You may be interested in *Paper* by Mark Kurlansky.  Basically, a history of the world through the lens of paper production.

Comment: In 19th century Britain at least, novels were often published as part-works - notably many, if not most, of Dickens' first appeared in installments in *Household Words* - which presumably made them more affordable to the general population.

Comment: You need to look at more than just purchase price. The Mechanics' Institute movement and the commercial circulating libraries both contributed immensely to availability and universal readership.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Affordable to the poor" is a slippery concept.

However, books [became much cheaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paperback#History) in the first half of the nineteenth century. Notable causes of this included steam-powered printing presses, mechanical typesetting, pulp paper mills, and the railway distribution network. These factors allowed the publication of cheap paperback books, which seem to have been invented by the [Tauchnitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauchnitz_publishers) family in Germany, and followed up by publishers such as [Routledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routledge#History) in the UK, aiming at the railway traveller market.

Answer (score 18):

The Gutenberg-style press process initially output [about 160 pages a day](http://www.answers.com/Q/Speed_of_the_first_printing_press), which was revolutionary compared to about 12 you could expect out of a human copyist. This got polished to the point where by 1600 a press could output [about 3,600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press#Mass_production_and_spread_of_printed_books) copies a day.

The next major advances came with the Industrial Revolution, [starting with cast iron presses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press#Industrial_printing_presses)(in 1800) putting out about 480 pages an **hour**, then steam presses (in 1814) outputting more than a thousand pages an hour.

Each one of these advancements can be thought of as a similar % reduction in the price of printed works. With the new steam presses [penny daily newspapers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_press#History) started to appear (vs. 6-cent).

However, we should backtrack a bit to the Bible and its importance to the history of printing. Most Protestant theology held that a person should read the Bible for themselves, rather than relying on a priesthood to interpret it for them. Inherent in this is the idea that a good Christian should be able to read the Bible, which means both literacy and owning a copy. This was more an ideal than a universal reality, but the Bible has always been the most-published book, and it was reality enough to actually [impact the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luther_Bible#Influence) in Protestant areas like Germany and England.

Comment: Also note that churches subsidized the printing and distribution of Bibles. The number of copies of the King James Version distributed in the 19th century was so high, and so many of them survived, that the vast majority of copies today are literally only worth the paper they are printed on to a collector.

Comment: This basically just restates the question and repeats the information already contained in it. The only new and relevant part is the mentioning of the penny daily newspapers, (which are not really books, but might get close to them by also publishing serial novels, which were probably the first sources of literature for the poor).

Comment: @vsz - The thing is, even the penny dailys really just spread newspapers to the Middle Class. The truly poor (as mentioned in the comments) even today don't have *any* cash to spare for such fripperies. That's why we have Public Libraries. So the only real way to answer the question is to show what the cost of printed media was at various times, and let the questioner decide when/if it qualifies.

Comment: "the poor" doesn't have to be those who are starving to death in a third world country, the "general population" mentioned in the title can be the general population in a first world country, where the poor (maybe not all of them, but surely most of them) can definitely afford cheap books.

Comment: @vsz - from reading Dickens, or contemporary authors examining the same era, it's easy to form the opinion that London at the start of the Industrial Age was awash in hundreds of thousands of people who literally were so poor that even the penny for a newspaper was beyond them.  And it seems that outside of the major cities, there was much less circulation of printed works, so that books were still a middle class "frippery."  Even today, instead of rookeries we now have seas of homeless people, who inasmuch as they don't even have the roof over their heads of those Londoners, are even poorer.

Comment: @user6297 : The working class in the USA comprises between 30% and 35% of the population, and the lower middle class is roughly similar. Most of Europe is not very different. Only a very small percentage of them are bums living on the street. And even someone who lives from paycheck to paycheck can occasionally afford a beer or two. And when a cheap book doesn't cost much more than a beer or two, we can safely conclude that the majority of the lower class in the developed world can afford books if they want. Therefore the homeless shouldn't influence the answer.

Comment: @user6297 Pennies were worth quite a bit more than today, mind you. A typical worker in 1800s London might make 10-20 pounds *a year*. Pennies were still silver coins at that point. So a relatively poor guy living on his own in London (still a much higher living standard than most people of the time; a typical house servant might make only 2-3 pounds a year, though they also got lodging and food) might have 80 pennies a day. Most of that would go on taxes (~30 d), rent (~25 d) and food (four pounds of bread could be ~20 d). And then there's clothing (easily half a year's income).

Comment: @vsz back in 18th-19th century, general population (~90%) *is* very poor working class; and what you'd call 'middle class' was 5-10% of population between the hand-to-mouth masses and the upper classes. So no, if something was available to middle class, you'd still consider that it was not available to most of population at the time.